# Check and add float values in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I am new to java and am trying to understand the arraylist. I am using Arraylist *theList* and *dummyValues*. I read the values from *theList* and update the float values in *dummyValues*. My code snippet is as follows
`

```
     public static void generateValues(ArrayList<Float> theList) {

     for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
         if (dummyValues.size()==0)
                 dummyValues.add(j, theList.get(j));

          else 
                dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));
                   }     
}
```

I trying add the values to the ArrayList *dummyValues* in the first condition and in the second condition if the size *dummyValues* is greater than 0 just update the values of *dummyValues*. I have considered this method to avoid duplicate copies.

But, when I execute it I get the following error :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

The error occurs here `dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));`

I know this is a trivial concept, any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that `dummValues` and `theList` do have the same size? otherwise you might be ignoring values or you get your exception. In this particular case it seems that `theList` is greater then `dummyList`.

Comment: `dummyValues` has only one element .but you call set for index 1 and etc...since there is only one element you can only set for index 0

Comment: @FastSnail thanks for the information. Now I understand you can only set on indexes which have elements in them. Is there method to avoid duplication of elements?

Comment: @ADI there is better collection types for that outher than arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this improvement. Change your method to this:

```
public static void generateValues(ArrayList<Float> theList) {

 for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
     if (dummyValues.size()==0){
             dummyValues.add(j, theList.get(j));
       }
      else if(dummyValues.size()==theList.size()){
            dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));
               }     
     else{
         dummyValues.add(theList.get(j));
    }
}
```

Check for size of both lists, if lists aren't same size it will add new element to dummy list instead of try to set element on nonexisting index.
In this case its possible that lists wont have same order.

EDIT: This is not right answer!!! Sorry I'm writting faster than thinking. :(
It works only if `theList.size() > dummyValues.size()`. I'll try to imprvove my answer ;)

EDIT2: Hello again.
Did some work and I'm back. I reworked your method and have second, in my opinion better, solution for you. Check this:

```
public static void generateValues(List<Float> theList) {

  if (dummyValues.size() >= theList.size()) { 
    for (float value : theList) {
      dummyValues.set(theList.indexOf(value), value);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (float value : theList) {
      dummyValues.add(dummyValues.size(), value);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it out and let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if **dummyList** is empty, when j is 0 it adds one element from **theList** to it, but when j is 1 you are trying to set the element on position 1 from **dummyList**. But at that moment, **dummyList** only has one element, which is on position 0. This is why you're getting the error.

One solution would be to ensure that you create **dummyList** with the initial capacity (or size if you prefer) as **theList**'s size.

```
 public static void generateValues(ArrayList<Float> theList) {

 for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
     if (dummyValues.size()==0){
             dummyValues = new ArrayList<>(theList.size());
             dummyValues.add(j, theList.get(j));

      } else 
            dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't accounted for the fact that if `dummyValues` only has 1 element in it, it will pass `dummyValues.size()==0)` but will only have an index of 0 since ArrayList begins counting at 0. So if we're at index 1 of `theList` it will throw you the exception in question.

You may have to add another condition for `dummyValues.size()==1)` that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the variables and initialised.

  ```
  dummyValues = new ArrayList<Float> ();
  ```
- Then you can do this checking before doing anything in code -

  ```
   public void generateValues(ArrayList<Float> theList) {

  if (theList.size() > 0) {
      for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
          if (dummyValues.size() == 0) {
              dummyValues.add(theList.get(j));
          } else {
              try {
                  if (dummyValues.get(j) != null) {
                      dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));
                  }
              } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                  //no element present here .
              }
          }

      }
    }

  }
  ```

This will check if `theList` has any value at all then start the loop. if the `dummyValues` is empty then add the 0th element or go on replacing the dummyValues with the theList values.

Give this a try and let me know if it works for you.